# Accessing Meraki Device using CMX - MSE API

Tags: cisco, management, meraki

How do I access a Meraki Device? Similar to the way in this tutorial.
[Cisco DevNet: CMX Mobility Services - Tutorials - MSE API Introduction](https://developer.cisco.com/site/cmx-mobility-services/learn/tutorials/mse-api-intro/#access-map-image-from-floor-specific-info)

Here is snapshot of the Public IP of my Meraki device

[image: Meraki Summary Report Page]

I replaced the Public IP in the tutorial with the Public IP address of my meraki device- the APIs do not work. I am able to use those APIs when connecting to the Public IP specified int he tutorial.

There is a SSL certificate preloaded in the tutorial  - the purpose of  certificate is to ensure the identity of the remote computer (as in msesandbox.cisco.com). Do I need to install a certificate on my Meraki device too? My take is it should not be necessary - at least to start with I should be able to use http (instead of https).

Ping to the public IP address of the Meraki device does not work.

what am I missing here? Any suggestions / pointers? Please help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. That tutorial for CMX Mobility Services is not designed to work with Meraki. Go here to get instructions on how to use CMX with Meraki:
http://developers.meraki.com/tagged/Location

Also there is a demo you can setup in 10 minutes here:
http://developers.meraki.com/shipped

Cheers,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

The Meraki API isn't accessed directly to the device, but through the Meraki dashboard. Meraki's full API documentation can be found [here](https://dashboard.meraki.com/api_docs).